# Why does a UserControl cause a Serialization error?

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization, user-controls

I have the following ComboBox in my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItemsProperty}" />
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
ObservableCollection<string> ComboItemsField = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItemsProperty
{
    get { return ComboItemsField; }
    set { ComboItemsField = value; }
}
```

This works perfectly!  I can add items to the Property and successfully Serialize the ComboBox Element.

My question is, why is it when I have this EXACT code in a UserControl.xaml and UserControl.xaml.cs, I get the following error on attempting to Serialize the control:

Cannot serialize a generic type
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservaleCollection'1[System.String]'

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you are "successfully Serializ(ing) the ComboBox Element", but the error is the expected behaviour for UserControls.

`XamlWriter` (which I assume you're using) cannot serialise bindings, meaning that it will attempt to serialise the actual values bound instead. Since you have a generic collection bound, it fails because `XamlWriter` cannot serialise generics.

You have two options:
Tell `XamlWriter` that you don't want to serialise the property:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItemsProperty
{
    get { return ComboItemsField; }
    set { ComboItemsField = value; }
}
```

or if you do require the items to be bound, then remove the generics problem by creating your own concrete class that derives from the generic. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538761/cannot-serialize-a-generic-type-system-windows-freezablecollection) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am using XamlWriter to Serialize.

Comment: One more thing.  You say that XamlWrite cannot seralize bindings, however, it successfully serializes the binding in Mainwindow.xaml and Mainwindow.xaml.cs.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's doing this. What XAML do you get for the combo?

Comment: You're right.  It doesn't serialize the binding.  I should have been more clear.  I wanted it to serialize the values in the collection.  Your answer helped me do that.  Thank you!