# How can i serialize a WPF custom control which has a property of type ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

I'm programming a WPF-window-designer application.
In the designer i can add customcontrols to the window and save the window by serializing the Canvas panel on which the added customcontrols are lying to XAML.

```
public string SerializeControlToXaml(FrameworkElement control)
{
    StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm =
            new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
    dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(control, dsm);

    string xaml = outstr.ToString();
    return xaml;
}
```

After that serialization i get the xaml as string and save it in a file which i can reload later.

Now my problem is that i added a new dependency property to one of my customcontrols which is of type ObservableCollection.
Each time i have set that property and try to serialize the canvas to XAML i get an error message:

"Invalid initials in 'ObservableCollection `1'. The sign '`', hexadecimal value 0x60, may not be contained in a name."

I never give the collection a name.
What's going wrong?

This is the viewmodel-property to which i bind the control:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedFormulas
{
    get
    {
        return selectedFormulas;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedFormulas = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFormulas");
    }
}
```

And this is my dependencyproperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFormulasProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFormulas", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(CustomNumericField));

public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedFormulas
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedFormulasProperty) as ObservableCollection<string>; }
    set { SetValue(SelectedFormulasProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Check the control's `x:Name` or `Name` to make sure it doesn't contain an apostrophe ( ' ).

Comment: It may be choking on the generic.  Make your property a return a subclass: `public class StringObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: Yes, it's the generic.  Make a non-generic subclass of the collection as shown in the answer to [Cannot serialize a generic type 'System.Windows.FreezableCollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538761/cannot-serialize-a-generic-type-system-windows-freezablecollection).

Comment: You shouldn't explictly use `ObservableCollection<T>` as property type. Better use a basic collection type and check at runtime if it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9128855/1136211

Comment: Thanks a lot dbc! That helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from dbc is the solution.

What i needed was a non-generic class instead of the ObservableCollection.

This is the new class:

```
public class SelectedFormulaCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{
}
```

And here the DependencyProperty in the customcontrol (Type of the property in the viewmodel must be changed too!):

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFormulasProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFormulas", typeof(SelectedFormulaCollection), typeof(CustomNumericField));

    public SelectedFormulaCollection SelectedFormulas
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedFormulasProperty) as SelectedFormulaCollection; }
        set { SetValue(SelectedFormulasProperty, value); }
    }
```